# jQuery - Getting certain tags in XML tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Let's say I have an `XML` like this: http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getInfo&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026&track=Just%20for%20Me&artist=Hinoi%20Team

I want to get the `<name>` inside of the `<artist>` branch. However there are other tags named `<name>` in XML as well. How do i target the one inside `<artist>` specifically?

Here's what I am using:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getInfo&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026&track="+yourTrack+"&artist="+yourArtist,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
          $(".loading").css("display", "none");
            $(xml).find('track').each(function(){
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                console.log("Success!");
                var name = $(this).find('name').text();
                $("#more").append("Listing results...\n");
                $("#more").append("Name: " + name);
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `name` is a direct child of `artist`, you can use `>` to get the child:

```
var name = $(this).find('artist > name').text();
```

Or, since there is no other `name` in `artist`:

```
var name = $(this).find('artist name').text();
```